# Nhibernate Linq Error on Single or Default

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm pulling my hair out over here and I'm not sure what's causing it.

I have the following LINQ query:

```
return Session.Linq<CandidateAccountEntity>().SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserName.ToLower().Equals(userName.ToLower()));
```

and its throwing the following error:

> Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

If I try to wrap it with a check of:

```
if(Session.Linq<CandidateAccountEntity>().Any()) {...}
```

then I get the following error:

> could not execute query [ SELECT
>   count(*) as y0_ FROM
>   [CandidateAccountEntity] this_ inner
>   join CFG.Account this_1_ on
>   this_.AccountEntity`1_id=this_1_.AccountId ] [SQL: SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM
>   [CandidateAccountEntity] this_ inner
>   join CFG.Account this_1_ on
>   this_.AccountEntity`1_id=this_1_.AccountId]

with an inner exception of:

> {"Incorrect syntax near '`'."}

Any help would be greatly, greatly apperciated. I don't want to get stuck here on friday afternoon :/

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598202/does-nhibernate-linq-support-tolower-in-where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToLower is not supported in the NH 2.x Linq provider. It works with the integrated provider in 3.x.

Comment: Hmm, well crap. Is there anyway to ignore case then?

Comment: Depending on the DB, you could use a case-insensitive collation for that field.